# How to copy files from a given directory into random directories of a target directory

Tags: linux, bash, random, copy, move

I have a directory `/Garbage` which contains files `Garbage-XXX` where 
`XXX` is a random number.

I have a directory `/Target` which has several subdirectories.

How can I tell bash to copy/move files from `/Garbage` into random subdirectories within `/Target`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a bash expert but I can hint the steps you need to take:

1. declare an `array` which will store a serial number with all the
   subdirectory names
2. iterate through all subdirectories of `/Target`
   with a `for` loop
3. place the loop number with the subdirectory name
   into the array declared in step 1
4. iterate through all files of `/Garbage` with a `for`
   loop (`for filename in /Garbage/*.*`)
5. copy or move each file within
   the loop to a subdirectory of `/Target` given by a random number
   between 0 and the size of your array (`shuf -i
   0-(${#arrayname[*]}-1) -n 1`) which then used to retrieve the random number's corresponding subdirectory name from the array